# Laravel seeder issue1

Tags: php, laravel, database, laravel-seeding

i use php artisan db:seed --class UsersSeeder in cmd and it gives me error.
here is my code.
can anyone help me out?

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

// use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

class UsersSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        //
        DB::table('users')->insert([
            'name'=>'Yasaman',
            'email'=>'Yasaman@gmail.com',
            'password'=>Hash::make('1234')
        ]);

    }
}
```

this is the error:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/5an383p1j4sm5m1/image.png/file

Comment: Can you copy paste the error message in your post?

Comment: its too big, i uploaded the pic of my error on media fire:
https://www.mediafire.com/file/5an383p1j4sm5m1/image.png/file

Comment: You can also place the image in your post. I think most users of StackOverflow won't download an image and open it.

Comment: i want to but the site gives me an error that as soon as you earn 10 reputation on the site you'll be able to embed images. so i have to wait. thanks for your helps

Answer (score 1):

You probably have created_at and updated_at columns on your User db Table. Just give them a value and see if it works.